# IRandomAccessStreamReference to image source

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Basically I want to display the thumbnail of a contact.

So I build a ValueConverter, that should convert the Contact.Thumbnail property (type is `IRandomAccessStreamReference`) to the source of an Image.

I can load a `BitmapImage` from an url or a `RandomAccessStream`, but how do I get from `IRandomAccessStreamReference` to an `RandomAccessStream`? Or am I already starting with the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the way I was able to get it to work. Get the path to the file and return a BitmapImage. You can bind to the BitmapImage as your image source.

```cs
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(((StorageFile)contact.Thumbnail).Path));
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It works, thanks. But I had to add "Pictures Library" to the Capabilities, first.

Comment: I just found out, since `Image.Source` can accept an `BitmapImage` OR an `Uri`, I can use `new Uri(((StorageFile)contact.Thumbnail).Path)` just as fine, without creating the `BitmapImage` ...